# Fetch top 10 products purchased by customer

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to write a SQL query in laravel/php, to fetch top 10 distinct products purchased by customer.

My table structure looks like this:

- `Orders` table (customer id, product id, etc....)
- `Products` table (product id, product name, etc....)

This is my query attempt:

```
SELECT products.* 
FROM products 
WHERE products.id = [SELECT DISTINCT (products.id) 
                     FROM orders 
                     WHERE customer.id=id->list(10)]
```

Comment: What does your current query return? Any errors? Wrong results? Also, please run `SELECT version();` to check MySQL version. You can add those information [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70796762/edit)

Answer (score 1):

I can see where you're going with your attempted query but unfortunately that won't give you top 10. Instead, you might not get any result at all:

```
SELECT products.* 
 FROM products 
 WHERE products.id=[SELECT DISTINCT (products.id) 
                 ^^^   FROM orders 
                       WHERE customer.id=id->list(10)]
```

The `=` means that you're looking for an exact match and your subquery suppose to returns 10 *rows* of data, which if you go with this operation, you'll receive this error.

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

But if you change that to `IN`, you might receive this error instead

> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

With your current attempt, your option is to do a `JOIN`. However, I'm wondering **how do you get your top 10**? I can see that you're looking for top 10 of products but base on what? Sales amount? Quantity ordered?

On that note, here's an example of top 10 products by quantity ordered.

```
SELECT P.* 
FROM Products P 
 JOIN ( SELECT product_id
         FROM Orders
        GROUP BY product_id
        ORDER BY SUM(Qty) DESC
    LIMIT 10) O 
ON P.id=O.product_id;
```

The subquery is not necessary but I'm imitating what you tried with a subquery albeit not exactly the same process. Here it is without subquery:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM Orders O 
 JOIN Products P ON O.product_id=P.id
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY SUM(Qty) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Or perhaps you're looking for top 10 by sales amount?

```
SELECT P.*
FROM Orders O 
 JOIN Products P ON O.product_id=P.id
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY SUM(UnitPrice*Qty) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=603a2b26e4066bdde580e19740147fb1)

Comment: yes this is what I am looking for, quantity wise top 10. but how write same in Laravel.

SELECT P.* 
FROM Products P 
 JOIN ( SELECT product_id
         FROM Orders
 where user.id=id
        GROUP BY product_id
        ORDER BY SUM(Qty) DESC
    LIMIT 10) O 
ON P.id=O.product_id;

Comment: I assume that the query you posted in your question is from laravel, correct? Won't it work if you just replace it with this solution? If I'm not mistaken, seems like you're trying to get top 10 from a laravel (js?) function to be used in the MySQL query however, the one I suggested is directly checking from MySQL table. The only thing you have to work out is how to return the results to your web-app, I assume?